# Mnemonics to correlate the definition of "asymmetric relation" and "antisymmetric relation" with the terms

Tags: self-learning, discrete-math, resource-request, set-theory

The definitions from Kenneth Rosen textbook are as :

> A relation $R$ on a set $A$ such that for all $a,b ∈ A$ ,if $(a,b) ∈ R$ and $(b,a) ∈ R$,then $a=b$ is called **antisymmetric**.

> A relation $R$ on a set $A$ such that for all $a,b ∈ A$  if $(a, b) ∈ R$ implies that $(b, a) \notin R$ is called **asymmetric**.

The problem which I face is that the terms "antisymmetric" and "asymmetric" seems to be same to me (something which is not symmetric) and as such, without revision after few days, I forget which definition corresponds to what. [I am bad at memorizing things]

Could anyone suggest me a suitable mnemonics to remember the same.

Comment: @BenCrowell I did not get the meaning of the conventions used by you..

Comment: @user2913 `Perhaps developing skill at memorization would be helpful to you. It can be useful at times. `: It seems so, my peers, seem to have no problem, they can simply mug things up, from derivation to definitions and at times even answers to exercises..

Comment: @user2913 your logic of "anti->something against or opposite" and "a ->without", makes quite sense, but could you just suggest me some other english word $x$ of this sort, such that anti$x$ and a$x$ brings out the difference, because overtime, I might as well forget your logic if I try to remember using $x= symmetric$ because currently the terms $antisymmetric$ and $asymmetric$ intuitively conveys the same meaning to me... I too have not used "asymmetric" that often except in statements like "human hands are asymmetric"

Comment: @user2913 thanks for the help

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Would the difference between "asocial" and "antisocial" help?

Comment: Vote to reopen. This is not fundamentally a mathematical question, but what practices are best applied to learn it.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I agree with you..

Answer (score 6):

First, let's note that the terms as used by Rosen are standard definitions, as we can see on Wikipedia ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_relation)), as well as other resource sites. There was some question about this in the comments, so I thought to clarify this first. Perhaps reading those articles will give an added perspective for the OP.

Now, I'm not going to offer a mnemonic -- I don't think it's a good practice. I almost always find there is some deeper meaning to mathematical structures, which when understood makes the relationships much clearer and makes a mnemonic unnecessary baggage. Usually I find that students reliant on mnemonic devices use them as a crutch, barely succeed in the current course of study, and fail to succeed at a later step.

That said, here are some comments looking at the Rosen text (speaking of Kenneth Rosen, *Discrete Mathematics and its Applications*, Seventh Edition) that may be clarifying.

In Section 9.1, the definition of *antisymmetric* appears in the main text, whereas *asymmetric* only appears within the exercises of that section. I would highly encourage you to work through each of Exercises 18-24 in that section, as the sequence walks you through clarifying exactly what the difference is. (The term *asymmetric* is only referenced in 4 other exercises throughout the rest of the text; it is largely only presented to walk through the sequence reflecting on the exact meaning of *antisymmetric*.)

**Spoilers follow for those exercises.**

---

For what it's worth, I don't think that the phrasing of the *antisymmetric* definition there is the best it could possibly be. When I present it in my class using that book, I rephrase it as the following (and this may be the only time I rephrase any definition in other than the exact way the book does):

> **Antisymmetric**: A relation $R$ on a set $A$ such that whenever $(a, b)
>  \in R$, then $(b, a) \not \in R$ (except when $a = b$).

Note that while the Wikipedia article gives two equivalent ways of phrasing this, my version shows a third way that I think is a bit clearer. Note that this is now obviously saying the same thing as the definition for asymmetry, with the added clause "except when $a = b$" at the end.

So this highlights that antisymmetry and asymmetry are *almost* the same thing, through which Exercises 9.1 walk the student. Any asymmetric relation is necessarily antisymmetric; but the converse does not hold. Specifically, the definition of antisymmetry permits a relation element of the form $(a, a)$, whereas asymmetry forbids that. So an asymmetric relation is necessarily irreflexive.

The property of antisymmetry is fundamentally of more interest, because it is used in the definition of a *partial order*, that is, a *poset*. See the start of Section 9.6: "A relation $R$ on a set $S$ is called a *partial ordering* or *partial order* if it is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive." See also Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

The property of asymmetry is not as interesting in this sense, because it's not independent of the reflexive property; as noted above, any asymmetric relation is automatically irreflexive.

Perhaps working through Section 9.6 on your own, and seeing the major use-case for antisymmetry (as opposed to asymmetry), will also be a memorable exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance. I shall remember it...